# How to stay objective after viewing your edit hundreds of times?

Tags: editing, video-editor

When I start editting something I'm very sharp about cuts that does or doesn't work. But as I go through the process, in which I watch the sequence hundreds of times, I get used to it, and becomes a bit blind to problems.

How do you stay objective and aware after viewing your own work so many times?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe the only answer to that is to take at least a 24hr break. Move onto another project or start something new. The number of times I have come back to something after a decent break and can all of a sudden see what needs to be done is shocking.

I don't believe their is a quick fix to this issue.

Comment: I agree with Mick79 here. A day (or even two+) might help you see the clips with fresh eyes. This might help too, to think of the video in terms of story and not content. What do you try to tell and what clips, and how much of the clip do you really need to tell that story.

Comment: Except in the reality of being a professional editor you almost never have 24hrs to take a break, so I don't think this is a good answer honestly

Answer (score 2):

What you are referring to is what I like to call Temp Love, you get used to something that is not finished.  The key is understanding where the end is, have a vision, and work through it...thats the key to being a good editor...knowing where you are, and where the finish is

Answer (score 2):

If you have a specific goal in mind, you can focus on that and just keep going until you're satisfied. 
More often than not, though, I find that taking at least one session away from the project to do something else helps. When you come back to it, your eyes and ears will feel fresher.